# Use of “yes” and “no” in answering questions worded in the negative

Tags: grammar, word-usage, descriptive-grammar, yes-no

In studying other languages (Korean at the moment) the use of “yes” and “no” when answering questions that are worded in the negative seems to be opposite English (at least American English) style. In Korean, the Question “You haven’t eaten yet?” Would be answered “Yes, I haven’t eaten yet.” While in English it would be answered “No, I haven’t eaten yet.” What are the English grammar rules for answering questions worded in the negative?

Comment: The *no* form in your example is idiomatic in English, but both forms of usage are admitted in English. It's inherently ambiguous (at least technically) if you just respond with a one-word *yes/no* answer.

Comment: Two other examples, both from parts of Africa....  In one country, they would reply "Yes" if they agreed with your statement:  Eg. Q: You haven't eaten yet? A: Yes  But meaning: Your statement was true - ie. "No, I haven't eaten yet".  In another country, they would answer (a double question?) with two replies - eg. "Yes... No"...  But it didn't mean **Yes** to Q1 and **No** to Q2... it meant "**Yes**, I understood your question, and the answer is **No**".

Comment: "Yes" is a proform for a positive polarity clause in English. "No" is a proform for a negative polarity clause.

Comment: @Lawrence: Re "The *no* form in your example is idiomatic in English, but both forms of usage are admitted in English.": By "admitted" do you mean that while the *yes* form is the less common one in use, it isn't considered grammatically wrong by most native speakers? And is this true for all possible contexts, or restricted to a limited number of (casual/spoken/etc.) contexts?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed In English, any yes/no question can be grammatically answered with either a yes or a no.

Comment: @Lawrence: Araucaria's comment above seems to disagree with that. So is the issue a matter of contention, a dialectal difference, and/or something else?

Comment: @HeWhoMustBeNamed I don't see a disagreement between Araucaria's and my comments. There are 3 levels at play here: whether something is grammatical (easiest to satisfy), whether it is meaningful, and whether it is idiomatic. Comments addressing one level don't necessarily invalidate comments addressing a different level.